# Monotouch treeview, expandableview or NSOutlineView

Tags: xamarin.ios, treeview, nsoutlineview

I want create a tree elements. For example, as this is [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Btibl.gif)

Can I use treeview, expandableview or NSOutlineView in monotouch?
Is there a tree of objects in monotouh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in or default control to represent a tree on iOS and frankly, you shouldn't really need one and most cases it should probably be avoided.

It's hard to fit a tree like control we have on our desktops in the touch world where you have huge fingers (so huge nodes) and with the nodes offset to show depth, there isn't much space left over. Adding it to the iOS environment would create a weird UX flow so you should re-think your design.

The common solution is to use tables with a detail accessory indicator and show a new controller the data (either a table or something else).

If you absolutely need one, you will need to roll your own. Check this for reference http://dotnet.kapenilattex.com/?p=566

Comment: Sorry? As I said, you could use a TableView. Search on docs.xamarin.com for a tutorial